# Certain projects in Visual Studio refuse to build, even when I attempt to build them manually

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I have a solution with a whole bunch of projects, but some of them for some reason refuse to build, even when I right click on them individually and choose "Build". I get messages like this in the output window:

```
1>------ Skipped Build: Project: Framework ------
1> 
2>------ Skipped Build: Project: Core ------
2> 
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 2 skipped ==========
```

Where Core is the project I'm trying to build and Framework is a project on which Core depends (and I made changes to code in Core but not Framework).

This is really frustrating because sometimes I have to make changes to code in one of these projects, and it seems that the *only* way to build them is to do a batch build, which takes a while.

Why are some of my projects refusing to build even when told explicitly to do so? And how can I fix this so they build normally?

Comment: What happens if you rebuild rather than build?

Comment: Check that those projects have a configuration defined that matches the active configuration of the solution.

Comment: Hi ekolis, any update about this issue?

Comment: Rebuild skips them too. The only way to build these projects is through batch build. If I check just the one project I want to build, it builds, but this is a bit annoying... And yes, there is a project build configuration for the current solution configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check **Build**-->**Configuration Manager**

Please make sure that these projects have the same **Platform** and **Configuration**. **Also**, do not forget to check **Build** option.

[image]

**And**, close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder of the projects and then restart your project.

**Besides**, if this does not work, please remove these projects from the solution file by right-click on these projects-->**Remove**. **Then**, readd these projects into the solution again.

**In addition**, you can also set **MSBuild project build output verbosity** to `Detailed` under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Projects and Solutions**-->**Build and Run** to check why these projects skip build.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The check boxes were already checked, but deleting `.vs`, `bin`, and `obj` did the trick!

Comment: @ekolis.Glad to know that it does help for your issue. Have a nice day!